# Can an interface method accept/return a struct while allowing the use of structs with the same shape to satisfy it?

Tags: go

I would like to create a library that exports a function that defines its own dependencies without consuming types from an external package (excluding std lib).

The issue is, if my dependency is an `interface` type with a method that returns a `struct`, consumers have to use the exact struct declared in the `interface`.

In situations where I have two or more libraries, each sharing the same `interface` signature however each package defining its own `interface` (interface segregation), they conflict when it comes to methods that return `struct` types.

```golang
package mylibrary

type Result struct {
  Value string
}

type IFoo interface {
  Foo() Result
}

func DoFoo(f IFoo) {
  f.Foo()
}
```

With the above code, anyone implementing this library must use the `mylibrary.Result` struct exactly to satisfy the `IFoo` interface.

In the case where I have multiple packages defining the interfaces of their own dependencies, this can become difficult and or impossible

See the following example: https://replit.com/@davidalsh/UsedCarefreeBrain#main.go

```golang
// main.go
// Creating an object that satisfies the contract roughly

import (
    packagea "main/package-a"
    packageb "main/package-b"
)

type Result struct {
    Message string
}

type Foo struct {}

// Even though Result is the same shape, this needs to
// return either packagea.Result or packageb.Result
func (*Foo) Foo() Result {
    return Result{}
}

func main() {
    dep := Foo{}
    packagea.DoFoo(dep) // Foo does not implement packagea.IFoo
    packageb.DoFoo(dep) // Foo does not implement packageb.IFoo
}
```

This seems like a strange limitation. Methods on an interface can return types like `string`, `int`, `[]int`, etc but not a `struct`.

Should I be returning an interface with getters/setters from `IFoo.Foo`, e.g.?

```golang
type IResult interface {
  Message() string
}

type IFoo interface {
  Foo() IResult
}
```

What if I would like to use a `struct` as an argument for a function? Should I also only accept an interface of getters?

```golang
interface IUserDetails {
  FirstName() string
  LastName() string
  Age() int
}

func SayHello(user IUserDetails) {
  fmt.Println("Hello", user.FirstName())
}
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `func (*Foo) Foo() mylibrary.FooResult`? That package is importing `mylibrary` to call `mylibrary.DoFoo` anyway.

Comment: My objective is to loosely couple packages. Having them share concrete dependencies means that packages that interact with each other and share similar self defined objects that implicitly satisfy a common contract cannot work

Comment: *"Having them share concrete dependencies means that packages that interact with each other and share similar self defined objects cannot work"* -- I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this... By "cannot work" you mean "will not compile"? In which case that's false as far as I'm able to understand your proposed scenario. Or, by "cannot work", you mean "it won't work as you hoped/imagined" it would?

Comment: Perhaps try to provide a [mcve] that produces the problems you anticipate. As of right know the code example in the question would work just fine if you did `func (*Foo) Foo() mylibrary.FooResult`.

Comment: Or perhaps are you asking if two types, with the same name and definition but defined in two separate packages, are the same? If that's what you are asking then the answer is, no, they are not the same. And to satisfy an interface the methods of the implementing type must match the methods of the interface *verbatim*. The method's parameter and return types MUST be the [**identical**](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_identity).

Comment: Say I have a two packages that don't know about each other, both exporting functions that consume an interface they define within the package. My plan is that I will, from main, create the shared dependency (that satisfies both interfaces), call the functions and supply that dependency. If the interfaces within both packages describe a method that returns a struct, declared independently in each package - it will not compile. I can make wrappers for each consumer though

Comment: I'll make an example - haha this is too abstract

Comment: Sounds like what you'll need is either a third package that defines the result type and which the other two will need to import, or the use of builtin types like `interface{}`. Or maybe Go1.18 generics might help you, but I haven't looked into them enough to be able to map your scenario to a valid solution.

Comment: "anyone implementing this library cannot use structs that look like the one described in the contract because Go requires a reference to the exact struct defined in the interface" makes no sense because there are no "contracts" in Go and no "references".

Comment: Apologies for the strange repl site, this one features folders so I could illustrate the concept. You're right about the third package being a shared dependency. It appears this is the space the standard library fills for a lot of common types that could be created. In my case I am trying to decouple libraries such that there is no intermediary packages and they are self describing (interface segregated). It's possible if the interfaces return `string` `int`, etc but not a struct https://replit.com/@davidalsh/UsedCarefreeBrain#main.go

Answer (score -1):

Define a type in a third package:

**common/common.go**

```
package common

type Result struct {
    Message string
}
```

Use this package in all other packages:

**main.go**

```
package main
import (
    "main/common"
    packagea "main/package-a"
    packageb "main/package-b"
)

type Foo struct{}

func (*Foo) Foo() common.Result {
    return common.Result{}
}

func main() {
    dep := &Foo{}
    packagea.DoFoo(dep)
    packageb.DoFoo(dep)
}
```

**package-a/packagea.go**

```
package packagea

import "main/common"

type IFoo interface {
    Foo() common.Result
}

func DoFoo(f IFoo) {
    f.Foo()
}
```

[Run the program on the Go Lang Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/pkpqrqG15Aw)